# C++ allocation of vector which contains newed pointers

Tags: c++, vector, stl

When using vector to hold pointers to newly allocated objects, such as

```
vector<int*> intP;
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
   intP.push_back(new int(i));
}
```

I understand that we have to deallocate everything that each `int*` is pointing to by ourselves, usually using `for_each` in `<algorithm>`. I am also aware that when the size of vector is increased to its capacity, it will reallocate more space by allocating new space with doubled size, copying everything from the old space to the new space, and destroying everything in the old space. But doesn't this cause memory leak, since no one is deleting the content pointed to by the old `int*`?

Comment: Right, no leak.  You might be interested to know that you can use a `std::unique_ptr` so you don't have to manually delete everything when you are done.

Comment: The pointers are copied, so the new `int*`s will point to the same objects. No need to delete them until you actually want to remove them from the vector. With that said you never want to do this. You want a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` or a plain `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Manual memory management is *so 90s C++*. These days you should use smart pointers.

Comment: @super I just realized that copying is doing what needs to be done..thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first better define what a "leak" is. A memory leak occurs when you have dynamically allocated memory floating around **that you can no longer reach.**

This means you have no way of deallocating it or even knowing where it is! This could be the result of pointers going out of scope before you call `delete` or a number of other things.

In your case, it's true that `std::vector` will destroy an array of pointers to dynamic memory, but before it does that, it copies all your pointers over. So since you're still able to reach your dynamic memory, there's no leak!

---

You may also be interested in [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) which will do the memory management for you so you won't have to worry about leaks at all!